duplicate keys, clustered indexes and composite keys
Hi so I have a system that I will have groups/users and their scores in a group. As an example,check these columns
GROUPID|USERID|SCORE|USERREGION

GROUPID, USERID they both will be duplicate keys(no primary keys.)
Imagine I have millions of users in the database. There is only 10 regions in total.
I want to query from,
GROUPID alone
USERID alone
or
USERREGION alone
or
(GROUPID,USERID) when a user wants to look up his/her score for a group.
I will be using indexes to enhance performance and performance enhancement is the most important concept to me as a developer.
Since I have different keys I want to query from, having 1 table and making it clustered (sorted) has no effect, whatsoever. Even if I had only 1 key I wanted to query from, I read that having clustered tables have no enhancement on querying performance, it is the indexes that do the job.
so for this case, having 3 indexes, GROUPID, USERID, USERREGION and one composite index (GROUPID,USERID) will be enough to achieve highest performance ?
There is no need to create multiple tables considering I will have millions of users, right?
For example I have 10 million users and 10 regions, at average 1 million user each table. Indexing should do all the job, and I don't need to sort the users on their region on the table, correct ?
Thank you for all opinions. I know it looks like opinion based question, yet it really is not. I am asking for best enhancement methods and if clustered tables help in this case, rather than an opinion.
Thank you

Provide: the output for SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename};, precise SQL text for all queries to be optimized, the data statistic (each grouping expression cardinality, approximately).

and making it clustered (sorted) ?? Do you know what is clustered index? In MySQL you cannot make any definite index clustered one, only PK candidate may be clustered.


GROUPID, USERID they both will be duplicate keys(no primary keys.)

If the pair (GROUPID,USERID) is unique, then you could have PRIMARY KEY (GROUPID,USERID)
WHERE GROUPID = 123 AMD USERID = 2345

and have any index with both columns.  (Keep in mind that a PRIMARY KEY is an `INDEX.)

GROUPID alone

WHERE GROUPID = 123

and any index starting with GROUPID

USERID alone

WHERE USERID = 987

and any index starting with USERID

or USERREGION alone or

WHERE USERREGION = 3

and any index starting with USERREGION

(GROUPID,USERID) when a user wants to look up his/her score for a
group.

Covered above??

clustered (sorted)

"Clustered" means that the data is sorted by that key.  A BTree index is inherently sorted, whether clustered or not.

has no effect

It depends.  However, there can be only one "clustered key".  On the other see also "covering index".

clustered tables

An INDEX, but not a TABLE, can be called "clustered".

will be enough to achieve highest performance ?

That depends on the queries.  Let's see the common queries.

There is no need to create multiple tables considering I will have millions of users, right?

Usually true.  Let's see the common queries.

sort the users on their region on the table, correct ?

Since a table is, by definition, a unordered list of rows, that is irrelevant.  However, having a clustered index on that table forces an ordering of the rows.  This is beneficially for some queries.  Let's see the common queries.
